# angularjs : how to convert html table to excel with multi worksheet?

Tags: html, angularjs, export-to-excel

I am using angularjs 1.5.8. I have learned there is one way can convert html table to Excel in angularjs, with service codes as below:

```
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
    var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
        format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
    return {
        tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
            var table=$(tableId),
                ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
})
```

In controller file, codes as below:

```
$scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
        var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
        $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
    }
```

There is one codepen example here:
[export html table to excel](https://codepen.io/marco27384/pen/pboLyx)

As you can see, above example can only create a Excel with one worksheet. If I have several tables, I need to place them in different worksheet, each worksheet can only has one table. How to realize that?

Comment: Does it work for you? For me only an empty table shows up in libre office. And did you notice that the export has two table tags?